# Windowed Envelopes in LaTeX

Tags: koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

I'm trying to get windowed envelopes sorted for letters.  My code is below.

```
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}


\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address \\ etc \\ London }
\setkomavar{fromphone}{1234567890}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{XXXXX \\ XXXX \\ XXXXX
\\ XXXX \\ XXXXX \\ XXXXX}

% \KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}
% \setkomavar{subject}{Wikipedia}
% \setkomavar{customer}{2342}

\opening{Dear XXXXX,}

%%%%%%   BODY OF LETTER

  \closing{Yours XXXXX,}


  % \ps{P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
  % \url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.}
  % \encl{Copyright permission form}

  \end{letter}

  \end{document}
```

This compiles fine, but it comes with my address at the top-left, when I want it at the top-right.  Also, there is one line right below my address, with that information repeated, and a solid line underneath.

[image: resulting pdf]

Can someone please tell me how to get my address on the top-right, and remove this additional line?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps try a different class? Scrlettr is for German letters and works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you need to add two option to class `scrlttr2` to get what you want:

```
  fromalign=locationright, % <==========================================
  backaddress=off, % <==================================================
```

With the following complete TeX code

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=a4,
  fromalign=locationright, % <==========================================
  backaddress=off, % <==================================================
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address \\ etc \\ London }
\setkomavar{fromphone}{1234567890}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{XXXXX \\ XXXX \\ XXXXX
\\ XXXX \\ XXXXX \\ XXXXX}

% \KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}
% \setkomavar{subject}{Wikipedia}
% \setkomavar{customer}{2342}

\opening{Dear XXXXX,}

%%%%%%   BODY OF LETTER

\closing{Yours XXXXX,}


  % \ps{P.S. You can find the full text of GFDL license at
  % \url{http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html}.}
  % \encl{Copyright permission form}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

you get the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Comment: Thank you, that works!

Comment: @GeorgeMcNamara If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).